# Controller not making associations in Rails because of wrong format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, associations

I need to make new associations for `Modification` model `if.save`. Also these associations need to be same as related `Entity` model has. But i'm getting this error:

> When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument.

`ModificationController.rb`

```
def create
    @modification = Modification.new(change_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @modification.save

        @modification.entity.boxes.each do |d| 
          @modification.boxes.new(d)
        end

        flash[:success] = "Success"
        format.html { redirect_to @modification }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @modification }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @modification.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

More info:

Each `Modification` belongs_to `Entity`
Both `Modifications` and `Entities` has_many `Boxes`.

Comment: Is `boxes` an association?  If so, `d` is a `Box`, so doing `@modification.boxes.new(d)` will produce the error message you have mentioned.

Comment: yes. Box is association.

Comment: `@modification.boxes << d ` you can do

Comment: Or, possibly `@modification.boxes.create!(d.attributes)` (at least in rails 3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to create a new box association using an existing `Box`.  We can grab the attributes of the existing box to create the new one.  However, an existing box will already have an `id`, so we need to exclude that from the attributes.

Following the above logic, the following should work:

```
def create
  @modification = Modification.new(change_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @modification.save

      @modification.entity.boxes.each do |d| 
        @modification.boxes << d.dup
      end

      flash[:success] = "Success"
      format.html { redirect_to @modification }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @modification }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @modification.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Now getting this error: UNIQUE constraint failed: boxes.id

Comment: Ok, hmmm... are you including the `.except(:id)` bit??

Comment: Should I put some of this code in `Private`? because now I get this error: ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError. Yes I include `.except(:id)`

Comment: Okay, you need to use the Rails 4 code.  I've just updated it... I left out the whitelisting of attributes.

Comment: I'm using rails 4 code but getting this: UNIQUE constraint failed: boxes.id I have whitelisted all atributes!

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 1):

**When you declare a has_many association, the declaring class automatically gains 16 methods related to the association** as the mention [Guide Ruby On Rails Association Has-Many](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference)

```
  def create

    @modification = Modification.new(change_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @modification.save

        @modification.entity.boxes.each do |d| 
          @modification.boxes << d # if d.present? use if condition there is nay validation in your model.
        end

        flash[:success] = "Success"
        format.html { redirect_to @modification }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @modification }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @modification.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Hope this helo you !!!

Comment: Looks right, but it makes new association for already made Box. I need to make entirely new Box. How can I do it?

Comment: Could you please add more _association_info_ about the model which have